# Is there a pattern for the irreducible factors and degrees of a characteristic polynomial?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, cyclotomic-fields

Let $Log(n) = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i \cdot e_i$, where $n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime, $\alpha_i \ge 0$, $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector. For example $6 = 2\cdot3$, hence:
$$Log(6) = (1,1,0,0,0,\cdots)$$
$$Log(15) = (0,1,1,0,0,\cdots)$$
$$Log(7) = (0,0,0,1,0,\cdots)$$
Consider the matrix $A_n = (Log(1)^T,Log(2)^T,\cdots,Log(n)^T)$. Then one can think about that $rank(A_n) = \Pi(n)$, where $\Pi$ is the prime counting function. For fun, we might compute the Smith normal form of this matrix:
$$D_n = U_n A_n V_n$$
I conjecture that $V_n = 1_n$ and that $D_n$ consists of $\Pi(n)$ ones on the diagonal. Now the mysterious part is the irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial of $U_n$.

Here is a list for $1 \le n \le 20$ computed with SAGEMATH:

```
1 x - 1
2 x^2 + 1
3 (x - 1) * (x^2 + x + 1)
4 (x - 1)^2 * (x^2 + x + 1)
5 (x - 1) * (x^4 + 1)
6 (x - 1)^2 * (x^4 + 1)
7 (x - 1) * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + 1)
8 (x - 1)^2 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + 1)
9 (x - 1)^3 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + 1)
10 (x - 1)^4 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + 1)
11 (x - 1)^5 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
12 (x - 1)^6 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
13 (x - 1)^5 * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
14 (x - 1)^6 * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
15 (x - 1)^7 * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
16 (x - 1)^8 * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
17 (x - 1)^9 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
18 (x - 1)^10 * (x^2 + 1) * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
19 (x - 1)^9 * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
20 (x - 1)^10 * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^2 + 1)^2 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
```

It occurs that the irreducible factors are cyclotomic polynomials $p(x)$ with $\deg(p(x))=\phi(m)$ for some number $m$.
But how does one compute the numbers $m$, given $n$?
I think this would give an interesting decomposition of $n$ in summands and products.

For example:
$$ 13 = 5\cdot\phi(1)+2\phi(4)+1\phi(5)$$
$$ 5 = 1\cdot\phi(1) + 1\cdot \phi(8)$$

I have tried to search OEIS for various related sequences but without success.

Thanks for you help.

**Edit**:
Here is some sage code, to get the matrix $U_5,\cdots,U_{10}$ and the corresponding matrices.

```
MAXN=100

def Log(a,N=MAXN):
    return vector([valuation(a,p) for p in primes(N)])

def Exp(v,N=MAXN):
    P = list(primes(N))
    return prod([P[i]**v[i] for i in range(len(P))])


def AA(n,N=MAXN):
    return matrix([Log(n,N=N) for n in range(1,n+1)],ring=QQ)


def UU(n,N=MAXN):
    D,U,V = (AA(n,N=N)).smith_form()
    return U


[ 0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1]
[ 0 -2  0  1  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0 -2  0  1  0  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0  0  1]
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0  0  1  0]
[ 0  2  0 -1  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  2  0 -1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  2  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  2  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  1]
```

**Update**:
Here are the matrices and corresponding characteristic polynomials for $n=23,29,31$:

```
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[ 0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  3  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
23 (x - 1)^11 * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^2 + 1)^3 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  3  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[ 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
29 (x - 1)^15 * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^2 + 1)^4 * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)
[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
[ 0 -2 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  3  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -3 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -2  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0 -1 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
[-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
31 (x - 1)^15 * (x^2 + x + 1) * (x^2 + 1)^5 * (x^4 - x^2 + 1)
```

**Update to the answer given by Denis Serre**:
I can not see how, $D_4 = U_1 \cdot A_4$ or $D_4 = U_2 \cdot A_4$:

```
sage: AA(4)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
sage: U1
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1]
sage: U2
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 0]
sage: U1*AA(4)
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
sage: U2*AA(4)
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
sage: UU(4)*AA(4)
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Just doing column reduction allows you to reduce A_n to a matrix of all ones, and then you use an appropriate permutation, so you should (in principle) be able to write down U_n explicitly, and maybe even represent it as a convolution.  I am not surprised that the associated polynomial is a product of cyclotomics; I am surprised that 8 appears in the representation for five through ten. It might help for you to list U_5 through U_10 to show us why.  Gerhard "Sometimes Having Enough Examples Helps" Paseman, 2019.03.18.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Thanks for your comment. I updated the question with examples.

Comment: Can you give some more entries in your list, say $n=23,29,31$?

Comment: I don't understand why $Log(15)\neq(0, 1, 1,0, \cdots)$.

Comment: you are right. sorry for the stupid mistake. i will correct that

Comment: @RichardStanley: Dear Professor Stanley. I updated the question with the examples you mentioned.

Comment: I am not sure to understand well the context. The Smith normal form $D_n$ is unique, but the pair of invertible matrices $(U_n,V_n)$ is not. Do you mean that the characteristic polynomial of $U_n$ does not depend upon the choice of the pair ?

Comment: @DenisSerre: Dear Professor Serre. I meant $U_n$ such that $V_n=1_n=$ diagonal matrix with ones on the diagonal. I am not sure if the characteristic polynomial will change for another choice of $V_n$.

Comment: The $r$ in the first line should be $n$, right?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: $r$ should be a large enough integer.

Comment: The corresponding integral module is isomorphic to copies of the integers, a copy per prime. For each permutation of the involved primes you get a different decomposition of the matrix, and the $U_n$ are simply permutation matrices. These have cyclotomic polynomials as factors of their characteristic polynomials.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser: Thanks for your insight in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made hand calculations for $n\le4$. It turns out that even with $V_n=1_n$, the factor $U_n$ is not unique. In other words, the factorisation problem is underdetermined. This is due to the fact that the few last columns of $A_n$ vanish. For instance, if $n=3$, the general $U_3$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0 \\ b & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore the characteristic polynomial can be any of the polynomials $X^3-aX^2-bX-1$. You may prefer to select the "simplest" matrix $U_n$, which gives you here the polynomial $X^3-1$, but how will you proceed for higher values of $n$ ?

**Edit** (after miscalculation in my original answer.) The case $n=4$ yields even more freedom. You may choose the matrices
$$U_4=\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ c & -2 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and even this list is incomplete. What is the simplest among them ? At least the second and third columns are mandatory. The corresponding characteristic polynomial $X^4-aX^3+(2-b)X^2-(2a+c)X+1$ can be any polynomial $X^4+\cdots+1$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: thanks for the update. i see know that the choice of Un is a particular choice of the algorithm and has not much to do with the decomposition of n